# Svg animation repeat

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, svg-animate

I have a svg image which is in the form of flowchart. As it is a flowchart, I decided to animation it in the form of flowchart. Now my question is how could I restart  the whole animation once it is completed.

What I used to animate :

1. Animate Tag
2. Each section of the flowchart is maintained in each group.

Since they are in sepearte groups i cant restart the animation. The solution for this can be in jQuery.

Help Me please.

Thanks

Comment: Show us the code you have currently, ideally as a [mcve]. It's certainly possibly to restart SMIL animations.

Comment: https://github.com/RandyRam/Randy

Comment: Can you add the minimal amount of that lot required to demonstrate the problem to the question itself please?

Comment: I have edited the file in the same link

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll need JQuery for that,
in line 85 and 88, change those to

`<animate id="first_arrow_fill1" dur="1s" attributeName="offset" begin="1s;third_text_anim4.end" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" />`

and

`<animate id="first_arrow_fill2" dur="1s" attributeName="offset" begin="1s;third_text_anim4.end" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" />`

respectively.

Basically, it says to begin at 1 second and also repeat it after the end of third_text_anim4.
Obviously it won't give the desired effect right away, but I think you can figure out the rest.

edit:
In the last animate tag (whichever animation you want to run last), add onend.
For example, I added it on line 45.

```
<animate id="third_text_anim4" onend="animComlete()" attributeName="fill" from="#0D5982" to="#684F28" begin="third_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
```

Then write the JavaScript function at the end of the file, before closing body tag,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function animComlete() {
        document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].setCurrentTime(0);
      }
</script>
```

This should do the trick !

Comment: I already tried of this and succeeded. Can you help me, how to retains back the default style and start animation as loaded for the first time

Comment: This code works perfect in Chrome, Firefox and not in IE9

Answer (score 0):

I could only figure out a Javascript solution. It has an onend tag inserted into the last circle to trigure the svg timer back to 0.

```html
<body>
  <svg width="100%" height="500" viewBox="0 0 750 160" id="svg1">
     <g id="layer1" transform="translate(0,-892.9134)">
      <g id="g4610" transform="matrix(0.78599195,0,0,0.78599195,25.527464,548.09428)">
       <ellipse ry="14.89975" rx="14.426742" cy="537.94202" cx="6.8185301" id="path4469" style="opacity:1;fill:#826333;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:0;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:1.32999992;stroke-opacity:1" />
       
       <g id="third_path" class="circle_hover">
        <defs>
         <linearGradient id="fill_anim3">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="#71D0E8">
           <animate id="third_arrow_fill1" dur="1s" attributeName="offset" begin="second_circle_anim2.end" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" />
          </stop>
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ded9d5">
           <animate id="third_arrow_fill2" dur="1s" attributeName="offset" begin="second_circle_anim2.end" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" />
          </stop>
         </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <path
         style="opacity:1;fill:url(#fill_anim3);fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:0;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:1.32999992;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m 290.25586,714.97266 c -3.7798,0.0116 -7.08387,0.11885 -9.64063,0.16992 a 14.426742,14.89975 0 0 1 2.54688,8.42578 14.426742,14.89975 0 0 1 -3.2207,9.36328 c 19.60354,-0.32683 44.81836,-5.80183 44.81836,23.96875 l 0,74.5 c 0,29.35747 39.47699,43.53689 68.68945,41.41602 l -0.0137,-0.25 a 14.426742,14.89975 0 0 1 -4.12696,-10.42579 14.426742,14.89975 0 0 1 2.46094,-8.3164 c -20.47912,-1.4012 -42.18868,-7.06713 -44.26562,-23.69727 -2.48013,-19.85839 -2.21769,-53.04506 0,-72.46875 4.49713,-39.38826 -34.71221,-42.75464 -57.24805,-42.68554 z" transform="translate(9.6628013,-251.10956)" id="path4577" />
        <ellipse
         style="opacity:1;fill:#c76875;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#0066B3;stroke-width:1.5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:91.544189453125;stroke-dashoffset:91.544189453125;stroke-opacity:1" id="ellipse4581" cx="413.39835" cy="611.03009" rx="14.426742" ry="14.89975">
         <animate id="third_circle_anim1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="91.544189453125" to="0" begin="third_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
         <animate id="third_circle_anim2" attributeName="fill" from="#ffa98f" to="#0066B3" begin="third_circle_anim1.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" onend="restart()"></animate>
        </ellipse>
        <text class="head_content" x="390" y="650">sample
         <animate id="third_text_anim1" attributeName="fill" from="#F67A83" to="#4F3CAA" begin="third_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
        </text>
        <text class="head_content" x="340" y="678">sample
         <animate id="third_text_anim2" attributeName="fill" from="#F67A83" to="#4F3CAA" begin="third_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
        </text>
        <text class="sub_content" x="353" y="700">sample
         <animate id="third_text_anim3" attributeName="fill" from="#0D5982" to="#684F28" begin="third_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
         <tspan class="sub_content" x="317" y="720">sample
          <animate id="third_text_anim4" attributeName="fill" from="#0D5982" to="#684F28" begin="third_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
         </tspan>
        </text>
       </g>
       <g id="second_path" class="circle_hover">
        <defs>
         <linearGradient id="fill_anim2">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="#71D0E8">
           <animate id="second_arrow_fill1" dur="1s" attributeName="offset" begin="first_circle_anim2.end" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" />
          </stop>
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ded9d5">
           <animate id="second_arrow_fill2" dur="1s" attributeName="offset" begin="first_circle_anim2.end" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" />
          </stop>
         </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <path
         style="opacity:1;fill:url(#fill_anim2);fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:0;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:1.32999992;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m 266.24609,462.17383 c -36.92375,-3.57967 -65.48691,13.85595 -64.78711,41.50917 0,0 -0.51423,51.85493 -0.50508,74.24685 0.01,23.45457 -27.31442,22.80234 -47.3058,23.13426 1.10753,2.14916 2.88782,5.74543 2.89096,8.18003 -9.6e-4,3.99327 -1.55391,7.81901 -4.31054,10.61914 3.27885,-1.0397 75.01148,3.93253 71.9746,-42.69184 -1.31839,-20.24093 0,-72.46832 0,-72.46832 -0.20538,-18.15802 14.03939,-23.13357 41.84376,-25.10351 -1.71604,-2.50694 -2.64034,-5.50017 -2.64649,-8.57031 0.006,-3.19035 1.00362,-6.29442 2.8457,-8.85547 z" transform="translate(0.5714286,1.42857)" id="path4573" />
        <ellipse ry="14.89975" rx="14.426742" cy="472.45868" cx="278.39835" id="ellipse4579"
         style="opacity:1;fill:#fb787f;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#0066B3;stroke-width:1.5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:91.544189453125;stroke-dashoffset:91.544189453125;stroke-opacity:1">
         <animate id="second_circle_anim1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="91.544189453125" to="0" begin="second_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
         <animate id="second_circle_anim2" attributeName="fill" from="#ffa98f" to="#0066B3" begin="second_circle_anim1.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
        </ellipse>
        <text class="head_content" x="250" y="450">sample
         <animate id="text_anim3" attributeName="fill" from="#F67A83" to="#4F3CAA" begin="second_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
        </text>
        <text class="head_content" x="235" y="385">sample
         <animate id="text_anim4" attributeName="fill" from="#F67A83" to="#4F3CAA" begin="second_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
        </text>
        <text class="sub_content" x="175" y="405">sample
         <animate id="text_anim5" attributeName="fill" from="#0D5982" to="#684F28" begin="second_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
         <tspan x="225" y="425"  class="sub_content">sample
          <animate id="text_anim6" attributeName="fill" from="#0D5982" to="#684F28" begin="second_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
         </tspan>
        </text>
       </g>
       <g id="first_path" class="circle_hover">
        <defs>
         <linearGradient id="fill_anim1">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="#71D0E8">
           <animate id="first_arrow_fill1" dur="1s" attributeName="offset" begin="1s" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" />
          </stop>
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ded9d5">
           <animate id="first_arrow_fill2" dur="1s" attributeName="offset" begin="1s" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" />
          </stop>
         </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <path
         style="opacity:1;fill:url(#fill_anim1);fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:0;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m 18.929688,529.44141 c 1.140051,2.17164 1.739409,4.60197 1.74414,7.07226 -0.0033,2.41521 -0.575072,4.79339 -1.666016,6.92969 l 36.876954,0 c 17.101683,0 11.124297,14.78094 13.525192,34.92207 7.304679,27.32129 35.935342,38.13518 62.612922,41.73111 -1.5457,-2.42739 -4.33484,-7.94712 -4.33733,-10.8524 0.005,-3.11453 0.90166,-5.74434 2.66254,-8.27277 -23.30774,-1.1068 -29.8766,-7.34118 -39.33413,-22.29658 -4.829034,-11.35821 5.68082,-49.23338 -28.703413,-49.23338 z" transform="translate(0.5714286,1.42857)" id="path4471" />
        <ellipse
         style="opacity:1;fill:#ffa98f;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#0066B3;stroke-width:1.5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:91.544189453125;stroke-dashoffset:91.544189453125;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="ellipse4571" cx="142.68405" cy="610.67297" rx="14.426742" ry="14.89975">
         <animate id="first_circle_anim1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="91.544189453125" to="0" begin="first_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
         <animate id="first_circle_anim2" attributeName="fill" from="#ffa98f" to="#0066B3" begin="first_circle_anim1.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" ></animate>
        </ellipse>
        <text class="head_content" x="115" y="650">sample
         <animate id="first_text_anim1" attributeName="fill" from="#F67A83" to="#4F3CAA" begin="first_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" ></animate>
        </text>
        <text class="head_content" x="108" y="678">sample
         <animate id="first_text_anim2" attributeName="fill" from="#F67A83" to="#4F3CAA" begin="first_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" ></animate>
        </text>
        <text class="sub_content" x="60" y="700">sample
         <animate id="first_text_anim3" attributeName="fill" from="#0D5982" to="#684F28" begin="first_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" ></animate>
        </text>
       </g>
      </g>
     </g>
    </svg>

<script>
var restart = function(){document.getElementById("svg1").setCurrentTime(0)}




</script>
 </body>
```